# Upgrad joomla 1.0.15 to joomla 1.5 with virtumart 1.0.15

Tags: joomla

I have a web application on joomla 1.0.15 with virtumart 1.0.15 and mojoblog beta v0.16 . There are some changes in virtue mart core file and table structure according to my application requirement. I want to upgrade joomla with virtuemart and mojoblog component. Please guide me tell me a proper way to do this. My application a have a lot user information and order records in database. Need your suggestion.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not going to be able to easily upgrade your site to 1.5. The biggest problem you face is that Mojoblog is not a 1.5 extension and is no longer supported. At a minimum, you will have to find a replacement for that. How you use it will determine which extensions are suitable replacements, but there is almost certainly an extension that will fit your needs. Blog type extensions are plentiful for Joomla 1.5.

In order to migrate from 1.0 to 1.5 you can follow the official Joomla guide - http://docs.joomla.org/Migrating_from_1.0.x_to_1.5_Stable